# Simply Cryptic #1

Tags: cryptic-clues

No back story, no setting, no theme, **simply** a **cryptic** clue to solve:

> One large cake performance

Since cryptic clues traditionally indicate the number of letters in the solution, I'll provide that as a hint:

> (9)

Hindsight note:

> This may be British English specific, possibly even dialectal. I'll make sure I avoid this in future clues.

<sub>Criticism is welcome as I plan to publish a few of these and I'd like it if the the future ones are better</sub>

Questions:
 
[Next](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42168/4729)

Comment: is it a single word or multiple words (mp 2)

Comment: The hint answers that, but I'll make it clearer

Comment: I am searching for a cake flavor, and its making me hungry!!So, is the flavor comes in the picture?

Comment: Welcome back @JamesWebster :)

Comment: @smriti this isn't my first cake based puzzle! http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57597/15394

Comment: Why did you do this >_< 'runs away and searches nearest bakery on G maps '

Comment: Is it a Ximenean clue?

Comment: I don't know what that is... But Google does. Yes, it is (/should be)

Comment: If it doesn't adhere strictly to those standards.. That'll make good feedback. =]

Comment: Wondering if [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_desserts#British_cakes) might be of any use ...

Comment: Are any of the clue words BE dialectal or is the answer dialectal?

Comment: @kirex, none of the words in the clue, nor the answer itself is dialectal, but a portion is

Comment: @JamesWebster  Now I'm confused what you mean by "portion" then, but I guess saying more would give too much away. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: I mean to say that part of the answer is a synonym.. The synonym is probably dialectal.

Comment: How many words?

Comment: @John One word (see the spoilertagged hint and also the first comments here).

Comment: @randal'thor, yeah, I saw both, the (9) and the comments, but not where the number of words was specified. I think I'm not firing on all cylinders this morning. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't a bun smaller than a cake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be:

> ABUNDANCE
>
>  'Cake performance' for a-bun-dance and this is a large quantity of something.

Comment: I think maybe you meant this, but it's not written. This might refer to a bundt cake? +1. Good answer.

Comment: If this is what James intended then it is not a good cryptic clue. The clue should have a definition, and there is no indication of "large quantity" here. "Large" won't serve, and anyway the definition should be separate from the cryptic part, not in between two parts of it.  Nothing to do with bundt cake.

Comment: @RosieF Would it be better if it was something like "Large: one cake performance"?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better: "Plenty of cake in a performance" (BUN in A DANCE).

Comment: @RosieF, that's good, I just don't think of a bun as cake. Maybe the British/American difference there.

Comment: @RosieF, this is the answer I intended. And good feedback thanks. I'll consider this in future posts.

Comment: "Bun" is indeed a regional synonym for cake, specifically a small individual cake, sometimes also called "fairy cakes"

Comment: My breakdown was: one - a, cake - bun, performance - dance. "Large" was supposed to indicate "abundance"

Comment: @James: The definition must go either at the beginning or the end, not in the middle. You should be able to split a clue into "the definition part" and "the wordplay part" by simply drawing a single vertical line. Also, definitions have to agree in part of speech with their answers, just like in regular crosswords.

Comment: @RosieF, that's a much better clue, although "plenty of" suggests an adjective rather than a noun. The "of" is only there to make the sentence grammatical and does not form part of the clue.  

Better might be: "More than enough cake in a performance", where "More than enough" is an adjective in the surface reading but can also refer to a noun.