# Simply Cryptic #2

Tags: cryptic-clues

No back story, no setting, no theme, **simply** a **cryptic** clue to solve:

> Mark hidden in plain sight and it's close. Listen!

Since cryptic clues traditionally indicate the number of letters in the solution, I'll provide that as a hint:

> (8)

<sub>After some feedback on my first question, hopefully this is a little better. However, criticism is still welcome.</sub>

---

Questions:
[Previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42117/4729) | 

[Next](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42297/4729)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may be

> INSIGNIA

Explanation

> 'insig' from hidden in pla*in sig*ht
>  +
>  'nia' from sounds like (Listen) near

Comment: wow, if it is correct, amazing deduction skills

Comment: Yes, it's probably correct. But it is unconventional to have only part of the answer hidden. Hidden answers usually contain the whole solution, otherwise you don't really know what or how much to look for.

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score -2):

My answer:

> Hidden in plain sight by Mark Buchanan. "Buchanan" is of 8 characters in length.

Comment: Not really cryptic though, is it?