# Simply Cryptic #3

Tags: cryptic-clues

No back story, no setting, no theme, **simply** a **cryptic** clue to solve:

> Leading to effect, endless pause in large town with LA reversal

Since cryptic clues traditionally indicate the number of letters in the solution, I'll provide that as a hint:

> (9)

<sub>After some feedback on my previous questions, hopefully this is a little better. However, criticism is still welcome.</sub>

---

Questions:
 
[Previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42168/4729)
 | 
[Next](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42531/4729)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's

> CAUSALITY

because

> endless pause -> AUS 
>  with LA reversal -> AL 
>  in large town -> CITY 
> C-AUS-AL-ITY
>  leading to effect -> (def)

Comment: This is the answer I was thinking of.. But it points out a problem with the clue! The first part isn't just topless!

Comment: yep, I was gonna say that. perhaps 'endless' is a better choice, both for the wordplay and for the aesthetics of the sentence.

Comment: Apart from clarity, "endless" has the advantage that is has a much better surface reading: A pause can be endless, but hardly topless. A problem with the construction is that both AUS and AL go into CITY, so they both should appear together before "in large town" unless you explicitly indicate that "LA reversal" is to be inserted. "with" is too weak for that; it suggests juxtaposition.