# Simply Cryptic #4

Tags: cryptic-clues

No back story, no setting, no theme, **simply** a **cryptic** clue to solve:

> Easy, he finishes walking strange, strangely.

Since cryptic clues traditionally indicate the number of letters in the solution, I'll provide that as a hint:

> (6)

<sub>After some feedback on my previous questions, hopefully this is a little better. However, criticism is still welcome.</sub>

---

Questions:
 

[Previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42297/4729)
 |
[Next](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52638/4729)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's

> SIMPLE

because

> he finishes = e + walking strange = limps; strangely = anagram
>  easy is the definition

Comment: TIL you cannot start an answer with the word "ha."

Comment: i don't get it ..  "e + .." why?

Comment: @lois6b, the "finish" of "he" is "e"

Comment: Hmmm. "He finishes" isn't quite the same as "finish of 'he'", is it? The adjectival use of "he" is okay I guess but finishes is a plural and therefore should mean more than one letter or one letter each from several words. And "walking strange" can't be "limps", it can only be something like "limping".

Comment: @MOehm FWIW I agree with you :P

Comment: There's a general rule in cryptic crosswords that you must supply the letters to be anagrammed, not give clues to them. So you could have "Limps strangely on end of toe -- easy", which supplies all the letters needed. ("On" only works if this is a down clue.)

Comment: I'm learning more about cryptic crosswords doing these than I have ever learned solving them! There are definitely some subtleties that I never picked up on.