# Simply Cryptic #5

Tags: cryptic-clues

No back story, no setting, no theme, **simply** a **cryptic** clue to solve:

> Starts to taste rather Mediterranean, some lemon too, regularly mixed with another's top condiment.

Since cryptic clues traditionally indicate the number of letters in the solution, I'll provide that as a hint:

> (12)

<sub>After some feedback on my previous questions, hopefully this is a little better. However, criticism is still welcome. It's been a while since I've written one of these so I may well have forgotten some of the rules.</sub>

---

Questions:
 


[Previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42531/4729)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

> TARAMASALATA

as this is

> A condiment and the initial letters of (Starts to)
>  Taste Rather Mediterranean, Some Lemon Too
>  mixed (anagrammed) with Anothers top - i.e. the letter A's

Comment: Impressive, especially since "another's top" for six As isn't really fair, in my opinion. Oh, and I think the second T comes from "too", which means that all consonants are already in order, so the mixing really is intertwining.

Comment: Was scrolling through a list of condiments and didn't get to this one by the time it was solved :) Did you know it off the top of your head? - If so :O :O :O

Comment: Yeah, I originally had "peppered" instead of "mixing". I only changed to mixing to make the sentence seem more natural. I've added one word to improve it without changing the rationale.

Comment: Thanks @MOehm - You are right about T from 'too' (not first 'to')!

Comment: @JamesWebster Adding that regularly would effectively make the CC no longer valid because you aren't actually using it and it's not a connector.

Comment: @n_palum Does "regularly mixed" to mean "put in at regular intervals" not work?

Comment: There are indicators for the extraction of every other letter, but not to my knowledge for interleaving. So maybe "Starts to taste rather Mediterranean, some lemon too, each followed by a condiment" or "Interleave starts to taste rather Mediterranean, some lemon too, with two triple-A condiment"? Not sure.

Comment: Mixed is the anagrind, my understand is that regularly mixed wouldn't be the same. But you could make your case for it I think